# Suggested way to print a custom quadtree in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, output

Using quadtrees in a project like so:

```
data Node = A | B | C  deriving (Show) 

data QuadTree = Null | Node Node (QuadTree) (QuadTree) (QuadTree) (QuadTree)
  deriving Show
```

These quadtrees are expected to be of up to depth 5 and as you can imagine it very quickly becomes hard to understand the contents of the tree when just outputting with the derived Show.

At depth 1, using derived Show, I'm already working with something like:

```
Node A (Node B Null Null Null Null) (Node B Null Null Null Null) (Node C Null Null Null Null) (Node B Null Null Null Null)
```

My current approach to simplifying this output is to use:

```
toArray (Node x child1 child2 child3 child4) = [x] ++ toArray child1 ++ toArray child2 ++ toArray child3 ++ toArray child4
```

... which simplifies things a lot: `[A, B, B, C, B]` in place of the alternative, but still becomes quickly hard to interpret as the tree grows.

Does anyone have any nifty tricks or tips on this they could please share? Any advice is much appreciated.

*Edit: to clarify, I just want to be able to see the contents of the tree as any viewable content in the least most migraine inducing way while debugging the algorithms I'll use on the trees*

Comment: Do you need it to be Haskell code actually representing the quadtree, any sort of valid Haskell syntax, any sort of plaintext, or just any sort of viewable content?

Comment: @leftaroundabout Any viewable content - as it's primary purpose is for me to understand the contents of the trees as I use them throughout. Thanks for asking, I'll clarify this in the question

Comment: For a compact representation you should generate the final string, directly, in some short format. You could simply represent `Null` as `N`, `Node A Null Null Null Null` as `A` (similarly for other terminal nodes) and `Node A t1 t2 t3 t4` as `(A, t1, t2, t3, t4)` where the subnodes are recursively represented. Alternatively, consider a 2D representation similar to how directory trees are shown by many file managers. Less compact, but possibly easier to read.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your aim is just to get a well-interpretable graphical view, I recommend not going through plaintext at all but instead generating HTML and let your browser take care for laying it out in a convenient way. A particularly easy library with which to do that is [yeamer](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/yeamer) (warning: it has quite heavy dependencies)

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Presentation.Yeamer
import GHC.Exts (IsString(..))

data Node = A | B | C  deriving (Show)

data QuadTree = Null | Node Node (QuadTree) (QuadTree) (QuadTree) (QuadTree)
  deriving Show

displayQuadTree :: QuadTree -> Presentation
displayQuadTree Null = "Null"
displayQuadTree (Node x ch₀ ch₁ ch₂ ch₃)
   =        "Node "<>fromString (show x)         -- Note: the ── and │ operators
                          ──                     -- are Unicode Box-Drawing 
      displayQuadTree ch₀ │ displayQuadTree ch₁  -- characters. You can also
                          ──                     -- use === and ||| instead.
      displayQuadTree ch₂ │ displayQuadTree ch₃

main :: IO ()
main = yeamer . displayQuadTree
         $ Node A (Node B Null Null Null Null)
                  (Node B Null Null Null Null)
                  (Node C Null Null Null Null)
                  (Node B Null Null Null Null)
```

When running this and pointing your browser to `http://localhost:14910`, you'll see

[image: example Yeamer output]

Readability can be further improved, even for large trees, with some CSS tweaks:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings, QuasiQuotes #-}

import Presentation.Yeamer
import GHC.Exts (IsString(..))
import Text.Cassius

data Node = A | B | C  deriving (Show)

data QuadTree = Null | Node Node (QuadTree) (QuadTree) (QuadTree) (QuadTree)
  deriving Show

displayQuadTree :: QuadTree -> Presentation
displayQuadTree Null = "Null"
displayQuadTree (Node x ch₀ ch₁ ch₂ ch₃) = "qt-node-box" #% do
     "Node "<>fromString (show x)
                          ──
      displayQuadTree ch₀ │ displayQuadTree ch₁
                          ──
      displayQuadTree ch₂ │ displayQuadTree ch₃

main :: IO ()
main = yeamer . styling
           ([cassius|
              body
                background-color: black
                color: white
                font-size: 24pt
              .qt-node-box
                border: 1px solid grey
                font-size: 70%
            |]())
        . displayQuadTree
         $ Node A
            (Node A (Node B Null Null Null Null)
                    (Node B Null Null Null Null)
                    (Node C Null Null Null Null)
                    (Node B Null Null Null Null))
            (Node B (Node B Null Null Null Null)
                    (Node B Null Null Null Null)
                    (Node C Null Null Null Null)
                    (Node B Null Null Null Null))
            (Node C (Node B Null Null Null Null)
                    (Node B Null Null Null Null)
                    (Node C Null Null Null Null)
                    (Node B Null Null Null Null))
            (Node A (Node B Null Null Null Null)
                    (Node B Null Null Null Null)
                    (Node C Null Null Null Null)
                    (Node B Null Null Null Null))
```

[image: How it can look with some styling]

Yeamer also makes it easy to interactively hide&expand subtrees: if you change the `Node` clause to

```
displayQuadTree (Node x ch₀ ch₁ ch₂ ch₃)
 = "Node "<>fromString (show x) ── do
     "..."
     "qt-node-box" #% (
       displayQuadTree ch₀ │ displayQuadTree ch₁
                           ──
       displayQuadTree ch₂ │ displayQuadTree ch₃
      )
```

then it'll at first show only

[image: all the tree still hidden]

and by clicking on the ellipses you can then expand only the parts that are actually interesting, like first

[image: top-level branches unhidden]

then

[image: one subbrach unhidden]

then finally

[image: one branch fully expanded]

This feature makes all of it usable even for *extremely* big trees, where a complete view would be overwhelming.

Comment: Can you add some indentation for the inner nodes to that? Or even style the boxes by giving them a border?

Comment: This is so impressive. As a Haskell beginner my mind is blown... So helpful, thank you.

Comment: @Rustang thanks, but again – caveat: Yeamer is a pretty heavyweight library, and also quite buggy. If you want something lighter, more performant&reliable, better use [blaze-html](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/blaze-html) directly (like Yeamer does under the hood), though that won't be quite so concise.

Comment: @leftaroundabout OK I'll keep this in mind, thanks for the extra info